# String value accessed by NSManagedObject getting truncated

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an entity in `Coredata` having a string field. When I tried to access this string value by using `NSManagedObject`, string is getting truncated.

```
MyEntity *entityOb = (fetching MyEntity object from Coredata)

NSString *myString = entityOb.stringField;
```

Consider `stringField` has the following value saved in `Coredata`

"This is

an example string ".

myString variable gives only "an example string". The first portion along with the space is getting truncated. The same issue occurs if the string has new line or blank line. Does anybody knows what's wrong with my code. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Is is in Core Data correctly? 1. NSLog just prior adding to Core Data including the length. 2.  NSLog just after retrieving from Core Data including the length. 3. Examine the Core Data store with an application such as [Base](http://menial.co.uk/base/).

Comment: It is showing correct value and length before saving to Core Data. But after fetching it is showing truncated string

Comment: There's no situation in which Core Data just truncates strings, so you'll have to provide more detail about what exactly your code is doing before you can get an answer.